# Converting a Array into individual rows in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Topic, which receives an array with multiple object in it like shown below.

```
[{"Id":2318805,"Booster Station":"Comanche County #1","TimeStamp":"2021-09-30T23:53:43.019","Total Throughput":2167.52856445125},{"Id":2318805,"Booster Station":"Comanche County #2","TimeStamp":"2020-09-30T23:53:43.019","Total Throughput":217.52856445125},]
```

when i load this in snowflake, it becomes one huge row, with all objects, i would like to store each object as individual row in snowflake, how can i achieve this, i am open to tweak at kafka level as or Connector.

My Kafka is AWS MSK, and i am using snowflake connector plugin for loading data in snowflake

[image]

Type of field
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snowflake's flatten table function to flatten the arrays to individual rows:

```
create or replace temp table T1 as
select(parse_json($$[{"Id":2318805,"Booster Station":"Comanche County #1","TimeStamp":"2021-09-30T23:53:43.019","Total Throughput":2167.52856445125},
       {"Id":2318805,"Booster Station":"Comanche County #2","TimeStamp":"2020-09-30T23:53:43.019","Total Throughput":217.52856445125}]
       $$)) as JSON
;

select VALUE from T1, table(flatten(JSON));
```

This is assuming that the Kafka messages are stored as variant type. If they are string, you can use the parse_json function to convert them to variant.

From there, you can convert the individual objects to columns if you want:

```
select   VALUE:"Booster Station"::string as BOOSTER_STATION
        ,VALUE:Id::int as ID
        ,VALUE:TimeStamp::timestamp as TIME_STAMP
        ,VALUE:"Total Throughput"::float as TOTAL_THROUGHPUT
from T1, table(flatten(JSON));
```

| BOOSTER_STATION | ID | TIME_STAMP | TOTAL_THROUGHPUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Comanche County #1 | 2318805 | 2021-09-30 23:53:43.019000000 | 2167.528564451 |
| Comanche County #2 | 2318805 | 2020-09-30 23:53:43.019000000 | 217.528564451 |

Comment: U are a life saver greg, i almost quitted on this, 
one small help instead of passing json data directly how can i refer it via the table itself where it resides in RECORD_CONTENT VARIANT

I am adding snapshot as well in my question

Comment: Is `RECORD_CONTENT` a string (varchar) or a variant? It appears to be a string but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: Its a variant, also adding snap in my answer to help better answer this

Comment: Not sure I understand what the requirement. The SQL does refer to the table, so maybe you just need to change the column name JSON in the sample to RECORD_CONTENT? So change `table(flatten(JSON))` to `table(flatten(RECORD_CONTENT))` ?